# Data conversion for Max() in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here is my query which i am not sure what causing a variable not showing result .

```
DECLARE @Display  int, 
    @MaxPediodPaid int,
    @MaxDate datetime, 
    @DealRef varchar(11),
    @QuoteDate datetime

SET @DealRef='140200100538136'
SET @QuoteDate = GETDATE()

SELECT @MaxPediodPaid=MAX(Period),@MaxDate=MAX(PayDate) 
FROM PaymentHistory
WHERE DealRef =  @DealRef;

SELECT @MaxPediodPaid , @MaxDate;
```

My declared variables `@MaxPediodPaid` and `@MaxDate` are `int` and `datetime` respectively. How can i convert the function values of `MAX(Period)` and `MAX(PayDate)` to assign values.

Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably, if you are getting `NULL` values, then there is no match to the `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks for addressing Godron, But i verified that and its returning a row.

Comment: On thing to try is to initialise your variables (example: Select @MaxPeriodPaid = -1, @MaxDate = '1900-01-01') prior to `SELECT @MAX....` and it should be overwritten by your select query. This will confirm if you have NULL in your existing row that is returned or no row at all.

Comment: Hmmm . . . You've declared `@dealref` to have 11 characters and set it to a string with 15 characters.  I stick by the assumption that no rows match.

Comment: You are right Gordon !! It solved the problem.